# short form of "not only, but also" or different?

Tags: word-usage

I read the following sentence in The Economist.

> An obsession with control is making China weaker but more dangerous.

Is it an omitted form of "not only, but also" as in "making China not only weaker but also more dangerous". Or it means "it is actually not making China weaker, but more dangerous"?

If it is the first case, and I suppose I just say "making China weaker *and* more dangerous". If so, it feels a bit odd that replacing "but" with "and" retains the exact same meaning.

Comment: I can't find the duplicate for this right now: the conjunction *but* used in this way is always the same as the conjunction *and* combined with an element of surprise.

Comment: Found it: see John Lawler's answer to the linked question.